# Removing values in an arraylist that DO NOT match a value

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am having some trouble with removing values that do not match a given value. At the moment I am copying over values to a new list and trying to clear the original list - but this is inefficient.

This is my code:

```
int size = list.size();
ArrayList<String> newList;
int count = 0;
newList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
    if(list.get(i).getForename().equals(forename)){
        newList.add(i, list);
    }
}
list.clear();
```

Is there a way where I can just remove an item in the `arraylist` if it does NOT match the name?

**EDIT:**
It works but then I might need a copy, as if I select a another name from the dropdown it will be referring to the old one

Thanks

Comment: You can simply use the `remove()` function to do it.

Comment: You can play with the methods of List as removeAll, retainAll

Comment: Did you give any thought about using Streams and Java 8? You could easily filter out those values and call distinct to make sure that the values inside your list will all be unique. If you don't want to make that call but still keep unique value, perhaps a HashSet would be better for you. Otherwise, just filter out values and create a new list

Comment: Although it has nothing to do with the solution, there is a small thing, which bugs me, when looking at your code: `newList` is a List of Strings, `list` contains something which has a method `getForename()`. Since `String` is final and doesn't have this method, there is no way you could add the elements of `list` to `newList`.

Answer (score 3):

A first thought would be to iterate on the list and as soon as you find an item not matching the value, you remove it. But it will create a Concurrent modification exception, as you iterate on list while trying to remove elements in it.
An other, still not efficient would be to iterate on the list, keep track of the indexes to remove, and after iterating on the list, remove them.

```
ArrayList<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
   if(!list.get(i).getForename().equals(forename)){
    indexList.add(i);
}
for(Integer index : indexList){
  list.remove(index);
}
indexList.clear();
```

Please not that this is not really efficient too, but maybe you were looking for a way to delete from the same list.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want, you might want to use streams instead (seems to be what you actually want, since you don't really seem to want to delete elements in your list):

```
newList = list.stream()
                .filter(e -> getForename().equals(forename))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or to perform your action what you might want to do:

```
list.stream()
        .filter(e -> getForename().equals(forename))
        .forEach(person -> doStuff(person));
```

Another way would be using iterators to avoid conflicts with modifications during iteration:

```
ListIterator iterator = list.listIterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    if(!iterator.getNext().getForename().equals(forename))
         iterator.remove();
}
```

**EDIT:** Since OP can't use lambdas and streams (because of Java-version), here is what nearly happens for the second stream (the forEach). I am not using the proper interfaces, since OP can't do so either. The difference to streams is, that they also might split this into several threads and hence would be faster (especially on multi-core processors and big lists):

```
interface Consumer<T>{  //this is normally given by the JAVA 8 API (which has one more default method)
    void accept(T t);
}

Consumer<YourObject> doIt = new Consumer<YourObject>(){ //This is what the lambda expression actually does
    @Override
    public void accept(YourObject e) {
        doStuff(e);
    }
};


for(YourObject element : list){ //since JAVA 1.5. Alternativ your old for-loop with element=list.get(i);
    if(!element.getForename().equals(forename)) //the filter written in easy
        continue;
    doIt.accept(element); //You could also use a method or expressions instead in this context.
    //doStuff(element);   //What actually the upper stream does.
}
```

You might want to look at the oracle tutorial (this chapter) to get a feeling, when this design is appropriate https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html (I have a strong feeling, you might want to use it).

Comment: I tried that and it does not work, it still returns some others as well

Comment: doesn't it throw `ConcurrentModificationException` ?

Comment: If I select another name for example, it doesnt work because I deleted the old list. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You could copy the list before using it or in your case you should use the streams.

Comment: @ctst you should probably delete first solution before somebody downvote you

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera Yep, good advice, the other two solutions are way better programming styles and the first solution shouldn't be spread.

Comment: Exactly how he should do it ! Good answer

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci At the same place, where your snippet is currently placed. If you want to read a short tutorial into streams I would suggest you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html. It is really worth the effort.

Comment: The lambda functions don't work - Android studio can't find `stream()`

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci I thought you were using JAVA 8 (it's a new feature). If it is only because of the lambdas, you can fix this by using local or anonymous classes instead of the lambdas, e.g. the part with forEach needs an implementation of the interface `Consumer<? super yourListObjects>` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). But since you said, you can't find `stream()` you should either update your JAVA-version or go with older code (like the iterators or the edit of what the stream and lambdas actually do.

Comment: My advice in this case would be to use a for-Each loop (without the local-classes but with methods) or if you really want to modify the list to use the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is

```
while (list.contains(value)) {
            list.remove(list.indexOf(value));
        }
```

Comment: You should at least respect the OP's code when submitting your answer

Comment: That has been covered by other answers. Just offering alternate solutions for OP and future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your List contains String objects the following should be what you are looking for:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext()){
    String foreName = it.next();
    if(forName != null && foreName.equals(forename)){
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
for (int i=0; i<list.size();){
    if(!list.get(i).getForename().equals(forename)){
        list.remove(i);
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't use increment your iterator inside your loop statement?

Comment: because if I remove the current element, the same counter i will represent the next element in the next run. If I increment it in the counter, it will end up skipping the check for the next element when removing one. Incrementing the counter only when the element is not removed, ensures all entries are compared.

Comment: Oh I see, your answer should have been upvoted then.. I don't know who or why is was done